# function that runs "statusFlag" from previous function which produces a boolean product

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am building a quiz app in HTML, CSS and javaScript.  I have been looking through other solutions for
 ideas on how to handle some of the functionality.
I ran across this code and am not sure I completely understand what is at play.

```
function validateAns(userChoice){
  let correctAns = questionBank[askedQs[n]].correctAnswer;
  if (userChoice === correctAns) {
  changeScoreBoard();
  displayRationale(true, correctAns);
  } 
  else {
  displayRationale(false, correctAns);
  }
}

function displayRationale(statusFlag, answer){
  return $(`#rationale`).html(
  `<label class="ansRationale">
      <button type="button" id="nextQ">next question</button>
      <img src="">
      <span id="rationale-text"></span>
      <span id="rationale-link">${questionBank[askedQs[n]].rationale}
  </span>
    </label>`);
  if (statusFlag){
  $(".ansRationale img").attr("src", correctAnsImg);
  $(".ansRationale #rationale-text").text("Correct!");
  }
  else{
  if(answer === undefined) {
     questionCounter--;
     $(".ansRationale img").attr("src", needsAnsIcon);
     $(".ansRationale #rationale-text").text('Please select an option');
  }
  else{
     $(".ansRationale img").attr("src", wrongAnsIcon);
    $(".ansRationale #rationale-text").text(`Incorrect, the correct
  answer was: ${questionBank[askedQs[n]].correctanswer}`);
    }
   }
  }
```

In the 2nd function displayRationale();   the term statusFlag is not one I have come across before and a quick google search did not turn anything up.  Is this a common term to accept the Boolean product from another function?  How does answer link to the previous function?  shouldn't it be correctAns?

Comment: `statusFlag` is just the name of the variable. It could be anything else. `displayRationale()` takes 2 arguments, depending on the value of `correctAns`.

Comment: the name of what variable though? statusFlag is not named anywhere in the rest of the code.  is it simply a place holder?

Comment: The name of the boolean argument according to `userChoice === correctAns`. It is simply a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a common term to accept the Boolean product from another
>   function?

Not necessarily, statusFlag in this case is just the prerogative of the code's author it is not a standard term. It does however seem to indicate that it is representing a Boolean value.

> How does answer link to the previous function? shouldn't it be
>   correctAns?

`displayRationale()` appears to take a Boolean and an answer. From the looks of it the user gets to decide weather they want to have the correct answers displayed or not. The variable `statusFlag` is set to true if they select yes, and false if no. Every time they provide an answer it basically asks that function `displayRationale()` if the it should show the correct answer next to the users answer.

correctAns and answer are both the same input with possibly different values. Most likely they they are both the output of displayRationale() depending on the the first Boolean input.